# get "running average" of a list

Tags: c#, list

Say I've got a list:

```
List<int> numbers = new List<int>();
```

and I'm trying to get the "running averages" of it. (Sorry, I don't really know how to call it).

For instance:

The first item in this list is `5`, the average of `5` is `5`, so the first average is `5`.

The second item in this list is `7`, the average of `5 and 7` is `6`, so the second average is `6`.

The third item in this list is `10`, the average of `5, 7 and 10` is `7.3`, so the third average is `7.3`
And so on.

Those first average, second average etc are the averages I'm trying to get. How would I go about doing this? I've been searching the internet but honestly I'm not quite sure what I should be looking for. :(

Comment: `numbers.Average();` will give you the current average of the values in the list.  Its not clear what if you need to save that to a new list or what

Comment: @Plutonix I think he wants to save it in a new list.

Comment: new `List<double>` and a `for` loop is all you need. IT's a really easy task... Have you tried writing any code yet?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Thanks @JohnSaunders, I shall keep that in mind for future reference. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
var averages = Enumerable.Range(1, numbers.Count)
               .Select(x => numbers.Take(x).Average())
               .ToList();
```

This will generate a sequence from `1` to `numbers.Count`. Then using `Take` it will get `X` element at each time (you can think `X` as an index, only difference is it starts from `1` and increases one by one up to the `numbers.Count`) starting from the first element then get their `average`.Put them into a list.

Comment: This is an elegant solution, but somewhat inefficient, since you recompute the average from scratch each iteration. The runtime will be O(n log n) while the simple solution that keeps a running sum is O(n)

Comment: @DaveM I thought so too, and no need to use a complicated structure for a simple problem like this.

Comment: @DaveM it's true. if the speed and performance is critical other approaches should be preferred.

Answer (score 5):

try this:

```
 string st = Console.ReadLine();
 string[] strs = st.Split(' ');
 List<int> numbers = new List<int>();
 List<double> averages = new List<double>();
 for (int i = 0; i < strs.Length; i++)
 {
     numbers.Add(int.Parse(strs[i]));
     averages.Add(numbers.Average());
 }
```

this will read the numbers from the standard input, the numbers are separated by space in input.

Answer (score 2):

The lists

```
    List<int> numbers = new List<int>();
    List<double> averages = new List<double>();
```

test data

```
    numbers.AddRange(new int[]{5, 7, 10});

    // get average of current List
    averages.Add(numbers.Average());
```

Such a list of averages all by itself usually doesnt mean much without some other data like number of elements, duration of time or something to qualify it.

This method is better suited when the moving average is not one for one with the values.  For instance, the app stores values.  Then periodically, say once a minute, the average is calculated and stored.

Comment: yours is probably more applicable to the OP's skill level

Comment: Not exaclty, seeing him accepting that answer, I don't think so.

Comment: wait, your answer doesn't work ! this won't get the "running averages"

Comment: It stores the average of the current list to the averages list, ie 7.3 for those values (as per the OP).  When the numbers change so does the new average.  It would be incumbent on the code to call it when there was only 1 and only 2 values in the list, which is what makes Mr Selman's answer better.  (and why `averages` is a list that can be added to).

Answer (score 0):

You need the "Running Average", not the average from the start over all items I assume?

The running average needs a number to tell how far back to look and one to tell how far forward to look.

This will give you the running average:

```
public List<double> GetRunningAverage(List<double> SourceList, int ItemsBefore, int ItemsAfter)
{
    List<double> TargetList = new List<double>() { };

    // Only makes sense if the list is > 1 of course
    if (SourceList.Count > 1)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < SourceList.Count; i++)
        {
            int LookBack =
                (ItemsBefore > i ? i : ItemsBefore);
            int LookForward =
                (ItemsAfter < SourceList.Count - i
                ? ItemsAfter : SourceList.Count - i);

            TargetList.Add(SourceList.GetRange(i - LookBack, LookBack + LookForward).Average());
        }
    }
    else
    {
        TargetList.AddRange(SourceList);
    }

    return TargetList;
}
```

You can then use it like this:

```
    List<double> FullList = GetRunningAverage(
    new List<double>() { 100, 5, 5, 6, 23, 10, 56, 32, 54, 1, 3, 85, 65, 49, 22, 65, 32, 5, 2, 4, 5, 89, 110, 55, 6, 56, 57 },
    3,  // Looking back 3 items
    3); // Looking forward 3 items
```